# Find if a full video was watched with unity ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am allowing users to be rewarded for watching unity video ads with a button click. When you click the button if the ad is ready it displays a video without the option to skip. I add points to the currency as well.

```
Advertisement.Show ("rewardedVideoZone");
currency += 10;
```

The ads run fine, at least in test mode, and you cannot skip them. You are also rewarded the 10 points for watching. The problem is that if I start an ad, close my app, then re-open it the ad is gone and I have the 10 extra points.

**Is there a way of finding if a user watched the full video to prevent someone from cheating it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, there is. What you can use is the [ShowOptions.resultCallback](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/Documentation%20for%20Publishers/Integration-Guide-for-Unity-Asset-Store) event to detect whether the user has finished seeing the ad.

Specifically, the event has a parameter **ShowResult**, which will have a value of ShowResult.Finished if the user watched the ad completely.

Partial Example

```
if(Advertisement.IsReady("rewardedVideoZone")) {
    var showOptions = new ShowOptions();
    showOptions.resultCallback += ResultCallback;
    Advertisement.Show("rewardedVideoZone", showOptions);
}

private void ResultCallback (ShowResult result) {
    if(result == ShowResult.Finished) {
        currency += 10;
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log ("No award given. Result was :: "+result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
      using UnityEngine;
        using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

        public class UnityAdsExample : MonoBehaviour
        {
          public void ShowRewardedAd()
          {
            if (Advertisement.IsReady("rewardedVideo"))
            {
              var options = new ShowOptions { resultCallback = HandleShowResult };
              Advertisement.Show("rewardedVideo", options);
            }
          }

          private void HandleShowResult(ShowResult result)
          {
            switch (result)
            {
              case ShowResult.Finished:
                Debug.Log("The ad was successfully shown.");
                //
                // YOUR CODE TO REWARD THE GAMER
                // Give coins etc.
                break;
              case ShowResult.Skipped:
                Debug.Log("The ad was skipped before reaching the end.");
                break;
              case ShowResult.Failed:
                Debug.LogError("The ad failed to be shown.");
                break;
            }
          }
        }
```

For more info check the [documentations](https://unity3d.com/services/ads/quick-start-guide).